# How do add editors but to only the unprotected cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have about 70 tabs that I am setting protection up for other than certain ranges which I want to be editable by all, however, if I protect them all, then share the workbook, everyone becomes an editor and can then edit the protected ranges.
Any thoughts?

```
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('A330'), true);
  protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('O13:O18'), 
  spreadsheet.getRange('O24:O29'), spreadsheet.getRange('O35:O45')])

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('A340'), true);
  protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('O13:O18'), 
  spreadsheet.getRange('O24:O29'), spreadsheet.getRange('O35:O45')])
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to protect the unprotected ranges (SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE) and give access only to certain users.

Comment: So I have tried this, but when I then share the spreadsheet and invite others as editors, it opens it up for all to edit and the ranges are no longer only locked to all but myself

Comment: if you share the spreadsheet with others, it should not add them automatically to the protected ranges, only to the protected sheets. Please check once again that you have protected the ranges or even better, share your code here